# Is $(A-A^{-1})$ skew-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, involutions

If $A$ is orthogonal, $(A-A^{-1})^T=A-A^T\neq -(A-A^{-1})=A^{-1}-A$

If $A$ is involutory, do we have an exception? In that case $(A-A^{-1})=0$, which seems trivial.

Comment: The zero matrix is skew-symmetric.

Comment: So is if A is orthogonal and symmetric, then $A=A^{-1}=A^T$?

Comment: Yes, symmetric means $A^T = A$, and orthogonal means $A^T A = I$, or, rearranging, $A^T = A^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't think I understand what is the question here.

Comment: If $A$ is orthogonal, then is the matrix $(A-A^{-1})$ skew-symmetric?

Comment: I don't understand your first equals sign. $(A-A^{-1})^T=A^T-(A^{-1})^T=A^T-A$, not $A-A^T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement that "if $A$ is orthogonal, then $(A - A^{-1})$ is skew-symmmetric" is indeed **correct** and is still correct when $A$ is additionally *symmetric* since the zero-matrix "counts" as being skew-symmetric.